# How to get a car spinning with AS3? A 360 degree view

Tags: actionscript-3

first post on here so be gentle!

I am currently designing an ad banner for my college assignment, the main feature i have is a car spinning, like a full 360 degree view.

Now I have took all of the media I needed and photoshopped them to how they need to look I just need some diction of where to go next.

I did want it where you can click and drag anywhere on the screen and it pulls the car around to where you want it, but I don't even know where to start with that! (please help if you can)

So I thought I would instead have it as a sort of image gallery with a next and previous button to select the next frame you want. But I don't like the way it looks so I was wondering if there was a way with action script where I could click on a button(next/previous) and the car would spin until I un-click? Rather than me having to keep clicking to load the next frame.

Also if I could I wanted a left to right scroll bar what could control the images, do you know any way of doing that?

Many Thanks in advance for ANY help!

Jordan.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a commercial solution:

[Krpano](http://www.krpano.com) -> very advanced, excellent support, highly recommended for panoramas, 2D object is a bit lacking tho. [Examples of 2D object](http://krpano.com/examples/objects/#top)

[Object2VR](http://ggnome.com/object2vr) -> **very** easy to use, not that great support, lacking API.

I would go personally for krpano because it is simply a superior tool. Great for panos, tons of possibilities. If you want it easy, go for Object2VR.

Now if you want to program it, and you need to program it, there are many options how you can do it. First of all, you need to load all the images into your app. Even if you don't maintain them in memory (that would be prefered, tho), you should load them so they are cached and can be reloaded fast. Your rotation can be achieved by "re-loading" the next image, or if you keep them in memory by simply referencing the next index of the array/vector. You always keep a reference index and upon click you simple increase the index and load the image. You than swap the images. It is too broad to explain, you will simply have to begin and ask for advice with some specific code.